# asp mvc fine grained view permission

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, authorization

I am build ASP MVC 4 web application and I need to create fine-grained permission on my views.
It means I need to show some actions to some users depend on their role, the data type request and other authorization rules.

On the controller side I put Authorize attribute where appropriate and create fine-grained code like so:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
  List<Survey> surveys;
  if (MyUser.IsSuperUser) {
    surveys = surveyRep.AllSurveys.ToList();
  }
  else {
    surveys = surveyRep.VisibleSurveys.ToList();
  }

  return View(surveys);
}
```

Because I'm building multi-tenant application any user who is not super user see only the "visible" surveys. Super user always see everything.

The problem now is how to create the same thing on the view side, without duplicating logic (DRY).

Currently when a user that is not super user and has only one tenant link to it I use this razor view logic:

```
<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Survey</legend>

        @if (!MyUser.IsSingleTenant) {
            <div class="editor-label">
                Tenant
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TenantID, ...
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TenantID)
            </div>
        }
```

MyUser return the currently logged in use and IsSingleTenant indicate if she only link to single tenant.

I'm afraid this will make my views messy with a lot of "if-then" logic.

How do other people solve this?

Thank you,
Ido.

Comment: Did you try to use role manager for this?

Comment: what do you mean "try use role manager"?

Comment: @IdoRan , just curious, what did you end up doing ?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with this approach. You could just put those sections in partial views to make it more readable:

```
<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Survey</legend>

        @if (!MyUser.IsSingleTenant) {
            @Html.Partial("Tenant")
        }

        ...
    </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: The problem is that it get more and more complex and it looks like it going the spaghetti code direction.

Comment: Use partials and/or editor/display templates, put common logic in custom helpers, ...